# Angular $filter for deep filtering in arrays inside JSON response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to filter the objects where the object structure is a little complex. I am looking a kind of deep filtering, where angular $filter works on the elements inside the array:

```
[
  {
    "schoolId": 12345,
    "schoolName": "ZXCVB",
    "classes": [
      {
        "classId": "C1",
        "students": 50
      },
      {
        "classId": "C2",
        "students": 100
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "schoolId": 98765,
    "schoolName": "QWERTY",
    "classes": [
      {
        "classId": "C1",
        "students": 100
      },
      {
        "classId": "C2",
        "students": 50
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

(This is an array of schools. Each school has array of classes and classes has Ids)
Here the thing I am looking for help is how can I filter on classId, so that it returns me the school object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), defining your own filter function.
Example:

```
.filter('classFilter', [function () {
    return function (input, classId) {
        if(!classId) return input;
        var out = [];
        input.forEach(function(s) {
            s.classes.forEach(function(c){
            if(c.classId==classId) out.push(s);
          })
        });
        return out;
    };
}]);
```

Live: 
http://jsfiddle.net/87yod9bf/2/

Comment: @Italo Ayres - Thanks! This is what I was looking for. The moment I asked this question I looked for implementing a custom filter. The one that I wrote is similar to this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with `filter` and `some`:

```
function filterByClassId(schools, id){
    return schools.filter(function(school){
        return school.classes.some(function(c){
            return c.classId === id;
        });
    });
}
```

It's up to you if you want to set it up as a [filter for angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters).